# Are glass containers suitable for "air plants"?

Tags: houseplants, containers, air-flow, bromeliads

I recently received three *[Tillandsia ionantha](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tillandsia_ionantha)* plants as a gift.  The set came with some teardrop-shaped glass "terraria" in which to display the plants.  Each container has a large hole to put the plant in and a few small holes above that, presumably for ventilation.

[image: Tillandsia plant in glass teardrop]

The kit also came with some sand and goofy "sea life" decorations, not shown here.

I know that cacti and succulents are often sold in similar containers, which are actually [quite harmful](http://www.cactiguide.com/article/?article=article19.php) to the plants.  Is it safe to use these containers with my air plants, or will I be dooming them to a slow death?  And if I do use the containers, what can I do to maximize their suitability?

Answer (score 2):

When I was a plant technician at a Botany Exhibit we had numerous bromeliads and tillandsia to take care of under varying conditions.  None of them were inside a glass or plastic bottle.

- display #1: glued to cork or bark with silicon adhesive (not silicon for bath and kitchen which contains a fungicide). Sprayed once daily with filtered water to remove chlorine.  Extremely high light levels from high pressure sodium lights that were on twelve to fourteen hours a day with ventilation
- display #2 glued to a piece of driftwood, sprayed once daily with filtered water. Situated in a south facing greenhouse with good light.

From these examples where the plants would grow, flower and die over a period of years. I recommend:

- any substrate: glue them to anything, more natural things like bark or cork are traditional
- light:  high light
- humidity: the more light the higher the humidity.  A sunny bathroom comes to mind as a good place
- water: spray or mist daily with dechlorinated water
- temperature: the higher the temperature the more a high humidity level or air circulation is required

I would remove the plant from the container it is in and attach it to something you like in a location that gets high light and where you will remember to mist it daily.  A bathroom or kitchen could be perfect. The container it is in is not suitable because:

- does not retain humid air
- not enough air circulation

Comment: This is good general advice, however it doesn't really address the issue of the container.  Just because you didn't use this type of container doesn't necessarily mean such a container is unsuitable.